# Parsing response from the WSDL

Tags: eclipse, wsdl

I've generated the web service client in eclipse for the OpenCalais WSDL using the "develop" client type. Actually I was following this [post](http://philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/09/16/open-calais-from-java-with-eclipse-extract-entities-facts-and-events-in-4-minutes/) so not really going in detail. Now when I get the results this way: `new CalaisLocator().getcalaisSoap().enlighten(key, content, requestParams);`, I get the String object, containing the response XML. Sure it's possible to parse that XML, but I think there must be some way to do it automatically, e.g. getting the response object in the form of some list whatsoever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the SOAP interface is already parsed. The englighten() method returns an XML string. When you call it with SOAP, this response is wrapped within even more XML. The SOAP library already parses the outer SOAP XML and returns the result of the enlighten() method, which is also XML.